# Extract nested data from a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested

I have the following reproducible example. A bit of a tricky one, that's about a complicated structure of nested data.

```
name <- c("impressions_unique","impressions_paid_unique","impressions_organic_unique")
period <- c("lifetime","lifetime","lifetime")
l1 <- list(data.frame(value = 33395))
l2 <- list(data.frame(value = 0))
l3 <- list(data.frame(value = 33395))
values <- c(l1,l2,l3)
title <- c("Lifetime Post Total Reach","Lifetime Post Paid Reach","Lifetime Post organic reach")
description <- c("Lifetime","Lifetime","Lifetime")
id <- c(125698,432566,759832)

df <- data.frame(name,period,title,description,id)
df$values <- values


name <- c("impressions_unique","impressions_paid_unique","impressions_organic_unique")
period <- c("lifetime","lifetime","lifetime")
l3 <- list(data.frame(value = 12345))
l4 <- list(data.frame(value = 55))
l5 <- list(data.frame(value = 12400))
values2 <- c(l3,l4,l5)
title <- c("Lifetime Post Total Reach","Lifetime Post Paid Reach","Lifetime Post organic reach")
description <- c("Lifetime","Lifetime","Lifetime")
id2 <- c(023698,212566,356832)

df1 <- data.frame(name,period,title,description,id)
df1$values <- values2


 Message <- c("The weather is sunny","Tomorrow is going to be raining")
 insights.data <- c(list(df),list(df1))
 created_time <- c(2020-02-28, 2020-02-25)
 ID <- c(062742003618463-1401305690071373,062742003618463-1401305690071374)

 full_df <- data.frame(Message,created_time,ID)
 full_df$insights.data <- insights.data
```

I want to have the columns of the full_df (except the insights.data) and additionally the three columns:"impressions_unique","impressions_paid_unique","impressions_organic_unique" along with their respective values. 
So the final dataframe should consist of the following columns:

```
   Message,impressions_unique,impressions_paid_unique,impressions_organic_unique,created_time,ID
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to unpack the nested structure using `unnest()` from the tidyr package. You need to do it twice because insights.data is a list containing a data frame, and within that data frame values is another list containing data frame. 
This will increase the number of rows by a factor of 3 because the data frame in the column insights.data has three rows. We can pivot these rows into columns using `pivot_wider()` (also from the tidyr package. The name is `spread()` in previous versions).

I hope I have understood the question correctly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

full_df %>% 
  unnest(insights.data) %>% 
  unnest(values) %>% 
  select(Message, created_time, ID, name, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```